# How groovy closures work internally?

Tags: java, groovy, lambda, closures, internal

A Java lambda can't modify variables in the surrounding scope (doesn't closes over). But how come Groovy closures can? What's its internal implementation?

For example, here, how come the closure can increment the outside variable `i`? Will an internal object be created for each iteration?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n;) {
    { -> i++ }.run()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `i` is boxed inside a mutable groovy reference. In Java, setting `i` would be changing a local variable of the method in which this loop resides. Which brings up a bunch of technical questions about what would happen if the function object leaves the method. But in groovy, `i` resides on the heap.

This explanation comes from the bytecode as I understand it, which you can get with the command:

```
javap -c <name of closure class>
```

Looking at the method `doCall`, first the `CallSite` object for the functor is looked up (since lambdas can share their classes, call sites are basically collections of captured local variables), and the specific `i` is retreived:

```
10: getfield      #29                 // Field i:Lgroovy/lang/Reference;
```

As you can see, the type of `i` is `groovy.lang.Reference`. Next, the number is incremented:

```
27: invokestatic  #51                 // Method org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.next:(Ljava/lang/Number;)Ljava/lang/Number;
```

After that, the result is loaded back into the groovy reference at:

```
42: invokevirtual #61                 // Method groovy/lang/Reference.set:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

It would be similar to doing something like this in Java:

```
for (AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(); i.get() < n;) {
    ((Runnable) () ->  System.out.println(i.getAndIncrement())).run();
}
```

Where I used `AtomicInteger` to represent a mutable `int` that resides on the heap, rather than in a local variable slot.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any proof? If I do `println i.class`, will I see that in action? Also, when does Groovy know it must wrap it? Compile or runtime? What about `@CompileStatic` in this regard?

Comment: @ArtemNovikov The proof was in the bytecode of the functor. I didn't include it at first because I was having trouble separating the Groovy boiler plate from the actual implementation. I have added my best effort. I'm not very well acquainted with groovy, I just happen to know how to read bytecode. Maybe you can test some things yourself. From my own testing it seems that groovy always wraps `int`s in a groovy reference, and `@CompileStatic` does not change that. `println i.class` will show `java.lang.Integer`, the groovy reference seems to be a hidden implementation detail.